# Get database output as one

Tags: php

i this problem that i am sure are very simple to some people but atm i just cant wrap my head around it.. here goes i want to plus all data outputs from a certain row with the code i have now it just outputs for example 12 2 12 14 but i want to get 40 instead of the above just to state a example here is my code

```
        $searchTimeScale = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM workhours WHERE case_project_id='$myCaseId'");
        while($timeFeed = mysql_fetch_assoc($searchTimeScale)){
        $workedHours =  $timeFeed['worked_hours'];
        $workedMinutes = $timeFeed['worked_minutes'];
        echo $workedHours;
        var_dump($workedMinutes);
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps using `SELECT SUM(worked_hours) AS worked_hours...`

Comment: Remember to NOT use mysql but rather mysqli OR PDO or something like that

Comment: @ITroubs i would never use mysql! but i am developing on a old system but thanks for mentiong it!

Comment: Haha legacy code is fun ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use aggregate function `SUM()` along with GROUP BY

```
SELECT SUM(your_hour_field)
FROM workhours
WHERE case_project_id='$myCaseId'
GROUP BY case_project_id
```

You don't technically need GROUP BY here since you are only querying for a single `case_project_id`, but I am showing it in case you ever wanted to SUM up across a full record set with aggregations on a specific field or fields.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer! this seems to be what i am looking for how ever i get null when i run this $searchTimeScale = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(worked_hours) FROM workhours WHERE case_project_id='$myCaseId'"); any idea why? thanks!

Comment: Just a quick bonus question how can i select both worked_minutes and worked_hours in one sql statement and sum the both up? thanks in advance!

Comment: @Anoxy `SELECT SUM(worked_hours) AS worked_hours_sum, SUM(worked_minutes) AS worked_minutes_sum FROM ...`  Of course you would need to think about how to add hours and minutes together so if a record is like 1 hour, 30 minutes, and you want to sum it with 45 minutes and have the outcome be 2 hours, 15 minutes, you would need to do some math. You might consider just summing up as minutes like `SELECT SUM((worked_hours * 60) + worked_minutes) AS worked_minutes_sum ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate in your SQL query by selecting `SUM(worked_hours*60+worked_minuts)`. That gives you the total number of minutes.

Answer (score -2):

Just keep a counter going:

```
$total = 0;
while($timefeed = mysql_fetch_assoc(...))) {
    $total += ($timeFeed['worked_hours'] * 60) + $timeFeed['worked_minutes'];
}
```

Comment: While technically correct, it is much better to let SQL handle that. Why would you transfer all the information over the network only to perform client-side aggregation?

Comment: because OP is doing `select *`, so who knows what the data usage requirements are.